# how to get clients actual time and timezone to perform system time check

Tags: javascript, dart, ntp

This might be a very vague question but please bear with me.

I am working on an application that requires me to perform a system time check on clients machine. The issue I am trying to address is, when clients travel across timezones and change their system time instead of changing the timezone it creates problems during the oauth negotiation. How should I go about addressing this problem in such a way that this issue can be self-detected when a client tries to login to the app rather than having to manually detect this kind of issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [`toUtc()`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.2/dart-core/DateTime/DateTime.utc.html) on a `new DateTime.now()` to convert it to UTC. It shouldn't be affected by time zones if it's in UTC, and the string representation will look like `"2013-10-18 08:52:16.861Z"` (the Z at the end means UTC).

You should be able to use a `DateTime` in UTC for OAuth negotiation. If not, please share more details; it's probably a bug in either Dart or your OAuth client.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like your timezones are pretty important so you shouldn't trust JavaScript system time with a 10 foot stick.

If I were you I would use PHP to geo-locate them and apply the timezone based on their location.

You will want to check out [Get PHP Timezone Name from Latitude and Longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126878/get-php-timezone-name-from-latitude-and-longitude)

Comment: The question is tagged for Dart so the server side and client side is Dart.  PHP really wouldn't play a role here.

Comment: Ah, im not sure what dart is just thought i would give my 2 cents. ( i only used php as an example, any server based language would work if dart has access )

Comment: Dart lang is google's abstraction that they develop the Adwords platform in. It compiles to javascript so there isn't a way to avoid javascript.   The answer above is just far superior when you consider it's dart.