# is it possible to get client side timezone using PHP without using javascript(Ajax) and cookie?

Tags: php, timezone

I know PHP run on server side and return send server timezone. is it any possibilities to get client side timezone. we can use any php library or anything.

Comment: Without Javascript, no. PHP is unaware of the client.

Comment: Unless you ask the client about their timezone and then transfer that information to PHP then you can't

Comment: I have get answer of this question. get latitude and longitude from this API **[ipgeolocationapi](https://ipgeolocationapi.com/)**. follow this code [j-bin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15535345/11099964).